# convert column into row

Tags: text-processing

I have file

```
head file1
12 0 
9 3 
12 0 
12 0 
12 0 
12 0 
7 5
```

I want to convert the second column into row

```
head desired

12
0
9
3
12
0
12
0
12
0
7
5
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` on this.

```
 awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s\n",$i}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

An easy job for `tr`:

```
$ cat input | tr ' ' '\n'
12
0
9
3
12
0
12
0
12
0
12
0
7
5
```

Answer (score 2):

Some other options:

```
fmt -0 file1
```

Or:

```
xargs -n 1 < file1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr -s '[:blank:]' '\n' < file
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="[ \t\n]+"} 1' file
```

Comment: This awk didn't work for me on Mac ( which is BSD awk I guess ), so might be GNU awk specific.

Answer (score 1):

Using xargs:

```
xargs -n1 < <(head input)
```

Or you could take advantage of the shells word splitting:

```
printf '%s\n' $(head input)
```